# Extract data from Excel sheet to multiple SQL Server tables

Tags: excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, data-integration

I have an Excel file with a few columns (20) and some data that I need to upload into 4 SQL Server tables. The tables are related and specific columns represents my id for each table.

Is there an ETL tool that I can use to automate this process?

Comment: The answer is Yes - there are multiple tools you could use. A little Googling would give you this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query uses `bulk insert` to store the file in a `#temptable`
and then inserts the contents from this temp table into the table you want in the database, however the file being imported is `.csv`. you can just save your excel file as `csv`, before doing this.

```
 CREATE TABLE #temptable (col1,col2,col3)
 BULK INSERT #temptable from 'C:\yourfilelocation\yourfile.csv' 
 WITH 
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2, 
    fieldterminator = ',', 
    rowterminator = '0x0A' 
    ) `


INSERT INTO yourTableInDataBase (col1,col2,col3)
SELECT (col1,col2,col3)
FROM #temptable
```

To automate this, you can put this inside a stored procedure and call the stored procedure using batch.Edit this code and put this inside `textfile` and save as `cmd`

```
set MYDB= yourDBname
set MYUSER=youruser
set MYPASSWORD=yourpassword
set MYSERVER=yourservername
sqlcmd -S %MYSERVER% -d %MYDB% -U %MYUSER% -P %MYPASSWORD% -h -1 -s "," -W -Q "exec yourstoredprocedure"
```

Comment: Thanks NT-Hero, I'll give it a shot and see how far I can go from here.

Comment: I was able to extract the data to SQL Server. Using the method you outlined, the problem can be solved. Also, I am evaluating a couple of ETL tools (SSIS, Talend Studio, Jasper ETL). Still work in progress though.